# Installing Windows 10 and deleting Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have Ubuntu 15.10 (64 bit) installed on my laptop and I can't get rid of it. Tried making a bootable usb of windows 10, permission error. Tried looking for a solid answer to making a partition of windows ... no clear answer exists.

I'm very new to Linux and looking to get back into windows. If a solution deletes Ubuntu 15.10, that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Change the boot order in your BIOS so that you can boot using your Windows Recovery Driver and then when installing Windows 10(from the recovery media) - just install it on the entire hard drive.
If needed, clean the mbr using

```
BootRec.exe /fixmbr
```

in command prompt.